# Greenberg-Hastings-Model: What kind of shift space is it?

Tags: entropy

I would like to read something about the entropy of the one-dimensional Greenberg-Hastings-Model - and I think maybe I can find something about that in the book "Symbolic Dynamics and Coding" - but I do not know which kind of shift space the Greenberg Hastings Model is.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of Greenberg-Hastings-Model, so I just googled it and according to Wikipedia this is a certain class of cellular automata (i.e. functions) on the full three shift over $\mathbb Z^2$ or a more general lattice.
I am pretty sure the book you mention does not contain anything about this class of CA. I would instead recommend looking at books about cellular automata...

Also  in order to compute or even approximate the entropy you would need to specify the underlying lattice ($\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z^2$, higher dimensional $\mathbb Z^d$ or a completely different lattice) and the exact CA rule (neighborhood, which patterns map to which symbols etc.) you are using.